# Google admob not display

Tags: android, admob

Google admob is not displaying.
I'm using Android studio. I first try android studio inbuilt functionality of advertisement activity - Banner ad and interstitial ad (New project > New AdActivity), but it doen't show me ad.

After that I tried many of ad project example download from internet and try it, but no one can show me ad.

I don't know why?

**Logcat:**

```
10-02 13:29:45.082 30269-30413/com.example.materialwallpaper W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=void java.lang.Object.wait!(long, int) from Object.java:4294967294 waiters=0 for 1.940s
10-02 13:29:46.962 30269-30447/com.example.materialwallpaper I/Ads: No fill from ad server.
10-02 13:29:46.963 30269-30269/com.example.materialwallpaper I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
10-02 13:29:46.964 30269-30269/com.example.materialwallpaper W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
10-02 13:30:47.029 30269-30269/com.example.materialwallpaper I/Ads: Starting ad request.
10-02 13:30:47.030 30269-30269/com.example.materialwallpaper I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB") to get test ads on this device.
10-02 13:30:47.030 30269-30269/com.example.materialwallpaper I/Ads: Please set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent background interstitial ad.
10-02 13:30:47.766 30269-31344/com.example.materialwallpaper I/Ads: No fill from ad server.
10-02 13:30:47.767 30269-30269/com.example.materialwallpaper I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
10-02 13:30:47.767 30269-30269/com.example.materialwallpaper W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is a fig, bro. Try the following:

1. If you app support Designed for Families.

   Bundle extras = new Bundle();
   extras.putBoolean("is_designed_for_families", true);

   AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
           .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
           .build();
2. Change the app package name or/and addid (perhaps you are banned)
3. Change the or/and ip connection to the Internet
4. Just wait. (if you have recently made the id)
5. request.setTesting(true);
6. With such questions can honestly write [to the support admob](https://support.google.com/admob/contact/performance_issues?cfnti=title.performance.reporting&cft=3).